# Can you use a text field and form button to change the html code on another html page hosted from the same server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Newbie Question: Can you use a text field and form button to change the html code on another html page hosted from the same server? I have 2 web pages and one is like an admin page and the other is just a view able page for others to just view. So i want to be able to use a text field and form button on the admin page to change the html code on the "just view able" html page so a group of admins can change the html code without going in to the server and changing the actual html code so the html code on the view able page can be changed quickly and on the fly using the admin page. Hope this makes sense what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this with HTML, as it requires editing a source HTML document, then saving it on the server for retrieval later.  You would need to write a program that runs on the server that reads the editable HTML page, displays it in the admin page in a large text box (for example), then after editing, with the click of a button saving the page content back onto the server itself.  I can imagine saving the page with a doPut(), but it's getting the page and placing it as is (i.e., uninterpreted) into the admin page's text area that you run into probs. Consider a servlet.

Comment: Is _" "just view able" html page"_ viewable by only admin users or any viewer accessing file online ?

Comment: Thank you Matt for your time in reading my question and answering. I always get great feedback from this community or always find answers to my questions. Thanks again!

Comment: @guest271314 - "just view able" is view able by any viewer accessing the file online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HTML and Javascript I don't think you can, it is client side, You can use PHP or other server side language.
For php you can see below example.

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
// we want a nice output
$doc->formatOutput = true;

$root = $doc->createElement('html');
$root = $doc->appendChild($root);

$head = $doc->createElement('head');
$head = $root->appendChild($head);

$title = $doc->createElement('title');
$title = $head->appendChild($title);

$text = $doc->createTextNode('This is the title');
$text = $title->appendChild($text);

echo 'Wrote: ' . $doc->saveHTMLFile("/tmp/test.html") . ' bytes'; // Wrote: 129 bytes

?>
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php

**EDIT**

For body or other way of using this is:

```
 $doc->loadHTML('<html><head><title>My Title</title></head><body>My content</body></html>');
```

Comment: Thank you for your time in reading my question and answering. I will give this a try and see how it works. Every answer is worth a try to see what fits and works the best for what I am trying to accomplish. :) Thanks again!

Comment: I was actually trying to do your fix, which is working half way for me. It does create the html page, but with no body. Ideally i would like it to copy the body that i already have for the "just view able" html but when hitting the a button on the admin page it would alter certain lines of html on the body it would be copying. I am almost there though thanks to the help of everyone so far! Everyone rocks on Stackoverflow and glad to have access to all the smart dev's of the world. :)

Comment: Glad that it is working, let us know the progress :)

Comment: Edited answer with other way of using above technique.

Comment: So now i can get the "just view able" to load when hitting the submit button on the admin page :), now my problem is, how to get the information in the text boxes to change certain lines of the html in the "just view able" page from whats in the text boxes when i hit submit, any ideas on that part? Then that will complete my quest :) :)

Comment: How about you use loadHTML and have template in there only part you want to see updated you add textbox value .$textboxvalue. and save/update html file?!

Comment: Karma, do you have a code example, im not really sure exactly how you mean?

Comment: Let's say you have textbox value in $example variable. so line would be following in loadHTML('<html><head><title>My Title</title></head><body>My content and my text: '.$example.'</body></html>')

Comment: Thank you for continuiing to help me Karma!!!! Karma could be a good thing or a bad thing depending on you look at it :) but in my case, Karma is great! :) :) Thanks again, i will try this and once complete will post my results here.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do here is produce a very simple content management system (CMS)

Assuming you know how to call a function on button press you will need a php function which will:

See [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for reading in a file

You would then need to do [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on the html you want to change

Finally you can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) to save the file

Comment: Thank you for your time in reading my question and answering. Yes, a very simple CMS basically :) I will give this a try and see how it works. Every answer is worth a try to see what fits and works the best for what I am trying to accomplish.  :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using PHP. First you should create form on the "admin" page:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
    <!-- ... -->
    <input type="submit" name="myaction_submit" value="Absenden" />
</form>
```

The action attribute specifies a script which handle the data of the form. Also you should choose a method. Usually you should use `method="get"` if you want to *get* data specified in this form. For example if you implementing a search. If you want to *post* something you should use `method="post"`. The main difference is that *get* uses special urls to send the data to the server. This mean you can create links (like `<a href="https://www.google.de/search?q=test">Search for test</a>`) which will send the same data to the server which can be sent by the form. Data transferred via *post* is hidden in the *body* of the HTTP-Request.

Now you have to create the PHP script to handle the data. Above I called it *action_page.php*. You can get the data written to the form with `$_GET` and `$_POST`. This mean you can check if someone has used the form above by writing

```
if (isset($_POST['myaction_submit'])) {
    // TODO handle form
}
```

Note that anyone can send anything to your server. This mean you have to check the permissions in this script too. Especially since you are talking about a admin page. It's not enough to hide the HTML-form if someone don't have the permission to do this. If you have a limited set of valid data, you have to check whether the data is valid in the script. It is not enough to check this using HTML and JS.

Now there are many ways to handle the data and there are many ways to generate the HTML-Code for the users page. You could manipulate the HTML page for the users directly or you could save the data in a database or file where you read it from the other page.

Comment: I have found that the best way to complete this is just to create a database one the server using MYSQL and have the admin page able to manipulate the data and the public page just essentially read the data, issue resolved, :) thanks all for your help!